# JSP history log from servlet

Tags: java, jsp

Some calculations are run via yy.java (let's consider as simple as it can be for the purpose of this question) and results get returned to xx.jsp (in a form x+y=z). I was wondering how can i have the whole history log showing on xx.jsp for all my previous calculations each time servlet is called. With example below, each time calculation is run old result gets deleted. I would like to have something like: 
    2+2=4 
    2*3=6
    7-3=4....

```
.jsp (file)

The result is : ${result}

.java (file)

request.setAttribute("result", result);         
    request.getRequestDispatcher(".jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have something like: 2+2=4 2*3=6 7-3=4....

Are you talking about using [logging in JSP files](http://www.tomred.net/tutorials/tomred-java-logging-in-jsps.html)?

If you are talking about somehow building a result value, you could use a `StringBuilder` in your controller and build it along the way as you make calculations.

```
int result = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// add something
results += x;
sb.append("added ").append(x).append(' ');
...
// multiply something
results *= y;
sb.append("multiplied ").append(y).append(' ');
// then add them to the model
request.setAttribute("result", result);         
request.setAttribute("resultLog", sb.toString());
```

Comment: I have a program that is working just fine, however i want to be able to see a calculation history log on the main page. So let's say my output is 2+2=4 (the result of my calculation), when i do another calculation with following output 2+3=5 previous one gets deleted. Is there a way to have them all showing until i clear everything (reload main .jsp page). So after i did these two calculations i would have:

Comment: Sounds like you will need to persist that information in a `Session` since it seems like it is across servlet calls, right @Cido_SB?